# Build AVMutableComposition from AVURLAssets in loop

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I'm working on an app that will need to concat a group of videos recorded from camera. Ultimately I'll have an array of URL's to work with but I can't figure out how to get two movie assets to concat properly. Here's some standalone code:

```
- (void)buildComposition {
    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_1049" ofType:@"MOV"];
    NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_1431" ofType:@"MOV"];
    NSURL *url1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
    NSURL *url2 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2];
    AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];
    AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *compositionInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];
    NSMutableArray *layerInstructions = [NSMutableArray array];
    CGSize renderSize = CGSizeZero;
    NSUInteger count = 0;
    for (NSURL *url in @[url1, url2]) {
        NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @(YES) };
        AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:options];
        CMTimeRange editRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0, 600));
        NSError *error = nil;
        CMTime insertionTime = composition.duration;
        NSArray *videoTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = videoTracks.firstObject;
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *videoCompositionTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [videoCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:editRange ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:insertionTime error:&error];
        if (count == 0) {
            AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
            CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6);
            [layerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(videoTrack.preferredTransform, scale) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
            [layerInstructions addObject:layerInstruction];
        }
        else {
            AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
            CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9);
            [layerInstruction setTransform:CGAffineTransformConcat(videoTrack.preferredTransform, scale) atTime:kCMTimeZero];
            [layerInstructions addObject:layerInstruction];
        }
        // set the render size
        CGRect transformed = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(CGRectMakeWithCGSize(videoTrack.naturalSize), videoTrack.preferredTransform);
        renderSize = CGSizeUnion(renderSize, transformed.size);

        NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
        AVAssetTrack *audioTrack = audioTracks.firstObject;
        AVMutableCompositionTrack *audioCompositionTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
        [audioCompositionTrack insertTimeRange:editRange ofTrack:audioTrack atTime:insertionTime error:&error];
        ++count;
    }
    // set the composition instructions
    compositionInstruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, composition.duration);
    compositionInstruction.layerInstructions = layerInstructions;
    AVMutableVideoComposition *videoComposition = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoCompositionWithPropertiesOfAsset:composition];
    videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
    videoComposition.instructions = @[compositionInstruction];
    videoComposition.renderSize = renderSize;
    // export the composition
    NSTimeInterval time = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSString *filename = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"video-export-%f", time] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"];
    NSString *pathTo = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/%@", filename]];
    NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathTo];
    AVAssetExportSession *assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    assetExport.videoComposition = videoComposition;
    assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
    assetExport.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = YES;
    assetExport.outputURL = fileUrl;

    [assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
        switch (assetExport.status) {
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
                NSLog(@"\n\nFailed: %@\n\n", assetExport.error);
                break;
            case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
                NSLog(@"\n\nCancelled: %@\n\n", assetExport.error);
                break;
            default:
                NSLog(@"\n\nExported: %@\n\n", fileUrl);
                break;
        }
    }];
 }
```

What I expect to happen is the first video plays for 1 second at 60% scale, and then the second video plays for 1 second at 90% scale.

What actually happens is the first video plays at both 60% and 90% at the start of the video. After 1 second, the video goes black but the audio plays correctly.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out for anyone who is curious. In my layer instructions, I was mistakenly building them using the AVURLAsset's videoTrack, not the AVMutableComposition's compositionTrack!

This line:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];
```

Should be:

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction *layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoCompositionTrack];
```

Comment: To anyone else that runs into this -- I was doing the same thing. Make sure you're using the composition track!